# Условные выражения

Tags: c, objective-c

```
      for (i = 0; I < n; i++)
      printf("%6d%c", a[i], (i%10==9 || i==n -1) ? '\n' : '  ') ;
```

Этот цикл выводит n элементов массива по десять в одной строке, отделяя каждый столбец пробелом и завершая каждую строку символом конца строки ( программа взята из "Язык программы С" денно Ритчи
Почему мы ставим в printf %c , что обозначает  i%10==9( зачем в делаем это ==9?) и также зачем мы делам i== n - 1 ??

Comment: @Иван Братчиков попробуйте прочесть саму книгу, а не только упражнения к ней. Все, о чем вы спрашиваете в этом вопросе, там есть

Comment: Я ее и читаю , но я не понимаю почему ==9?

Comment: значит плохо читаете. Читали про оператор **%**? Поняли что он делает?

Comment: Да, я про него знаю, я только на понимаю зачем мы ставим ==9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Опасный Код!**

```
for(i = 0; I < n; i++)
```

Тут переменная i(маленькая) и I(большая) - разные. Так что, у тебя программа не должна работать.

По делу.

**Вопрос №1 "Почему мы ставим в printf %c"**

Это спецификатор вывода в printf. Так сказать, маска. На это место встанет символ, который позже вычислится.

**Вопрос №2 "что обозначает i%10==9( зачем в делаем это ==9?) "**

Это проверка условия, равен ли i 9 по модулю 10. То есть, равна ли 9 последняя цифра числа i.

Вообще, там стоит макрос: "Если последняя цифра i равна 9, то переводим строки, иначе ставим пробел."

**Вопрос № 3 "зачем мы делам i== n - 1?"**

В конце вывода, после последнего числа, следует поставить знак перевода строки, иначе не понятен будет вывод. Только и всё.

Answer (score 2):

Просто же - отчет начинается с нуля, следовательно, чтобы найти каждый 10-ый элемент, нужно проверить, будет ли остаток при делении на 10 равен 9.